# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: mysqli, xampp

I'm only trying to connect my website to a database using xampp, but this error keeps appearing.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it.

I tried alot of things but the problem still persists.
please help.

Comment: Is mysql service running?

Comment: what to do: 1) make sure mysql is actually running, 2) check for the port, is it open?, 3) check firewall, does your firewall actively blocks port 3306? you can check point 1 and 2 through XAMPP control panel.

Comment: yes, i'm actually using another website that uses the same database and it's working fine.

Comment: Also, i tested it on a different machine also with xampp installed and it works fine, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to connect from local-machine? If is it, try to change value of DB_HOST to localhost or 127.0.0.1.